# "memory errors" in python application with available and free amount of memory

Tags: python, windows, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

My app is written in `Python` 3.7.5 with `MySQL` and running in a computer with Windows 10, 32GB of memory and 24 logical cores.

[image]

The App is stopping with a memory error in different modules, such as `Numpy` or `Python` itself or `MySQL` (below there are two messages that I received, recently).

- numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 830MiB for an array with shape (1834, 59304) and data type float64
- sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1041, "Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space")
  [SQL: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode']
  (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

However, every time it stopped with these errors it still had more than 10GB free memory (see the image below). The memory errors are more frequent when using multiprocessing (up to 22 simultaneous tasks). But they also occur when running in a single thread.

Any idea of what can be happening?

[image: memory available when one of the memory errors occurred]

Comment: You seem to be confusing virtual address space and RAM. Available RAM is mostly a meaningless metric.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help. I will study what virtual address space is and how to manage it in Python. If you have any suggestion of  learning literature or sites, that would be quite helpful.

Comment: You are probably running a 32-bit process, so your address space is limited to 2, 3, or 4GB (depending on system settings and the binary executing). The quick fix is running the 64-bit Python interpreter.

Comment: My Python interpreter is already the 64 bits version (see the image I added to the question above).

Comment: In that case you're out of address space. There's little you can do next to consuming less. Though that seems not very plausible, seeing as you get several TB of address space for 64-bit applications. Then again, I don't know whether Python has its own set of limits below the OS-provided limits.

Comment: Ok. I agree that it seems not very plausible as some TB would be more than enough to multiple processes of this app. Look that one of the errors says "Unable to allocate 830MiB", it is a tiny number compared to 1 TB. I will try to find if Python has its own set of limits. Thank you.